# Checking a subcollection in a firebase document if it contains the user

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, tailwind-css

Currently i have a container which shows the upcoming activites . So my plan is that if the user open the page it shows the upcoming activities and can click the participate button to participate that activity. By doing this, that particular activity will create a document in a subcollection for that activity and each document id is saved as the current user id . If the current user id is contain in that particular activity collection, the participate button will turn to participated and is disable. Ive managed to make current user id to be save in that activity but ive not managed to handle the button to check if there is current user id in it to make it disable. Any ideas if this is a function, flow or maybe css problem that i have to fix

**EDITED**
Ok I have editted the code which I think did not produce the results i wanted. Supposedly I want everytime user open this UpcomingActivity function to check if the particular activity has the current user as a participant or not but for now . It managed to turn disable when I the current user first time click participate but after refresh it returns back to its default state but couldnt click participate anymore because its participation is already in it

Below is my current code for this page.

```
  const participateInActivity = async (activityId) => {
    if (!userId) {
     
      return;
    }
   
    const activityDocRef = doc(db, 'Activity', activityId);
    const participantRef = collection(activityDocRef, 'Participants');
    const participantQuery = query(participantRef, where('uid', '==', userId));
    const participantQuerySnapshot = await getDocs(participantQuery);

    if (participantQuerySnapshot.size === 0) {
      const participantDocRef = doc(participantRef, userId);

      await setDoc(participantDocRef, {
        uid: userId,
        name: userName,
      }, { merge: true });

      const updatedActivityData = activityData.map((activity) => {
        if (activity.id === activityId) {
          return { ...activity, participantStatus: true };
        }
        return activity;
      });

      setActivityData(updatedActivityData);
    }
  };
```

This Button Should handle the change if user already participated in the activity

```
                  <button
                    type='submit'
                    className={`rounded-[20px] w-[200px] shadow ${
                      activity.participantStatus
                        ? 'bg-green-300 opacity-50 cursor-not-allowed'
                        : 'bg-green-300 hover:bg-green-200 border-b-4 border-green-400 hover:border-green-300'
                    }`}
                    onClick={() => participateInActivity(activity.id)}
                    disabled={activity.participantStatus}
                  >
                    {activity.participantStatus ? 'PARTICIPATED' : 'PARTICIPATE'}
                  </button>
```

Comment: There's quite a lot of code in your question, and while it looks fine at first glance it's hard to be certain at this scope. Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger, so I recommend that you do some local debugging and tell us the results of that. So set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, and then run the code in a debugger. Each time it hits a breakpoint,  check the value of each variable on that line. If you do this, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have already editted and leave out the code that i have a problem with. If you wont mind, could you take a look